# Multiple time pickers on one screen make app freeze on phones with iOS15+ only

Tags: ios, objective-c, extjs, wkwebview, ios15

The backend of this app was made with ExtJS. The frontend is Objective-C, where the webpages are displayed with a WKWebView. It is legacy, and there is no documentation or people with knowledge or experience within the company regarding the app.

My app freezes when I select a new time picker.
I have multiple (4) native time pickers on one screen, which are displayed in a web page through WKWebView.
Whenever the user closes the picker by selecting the screen anywhere but on the picker, and choosing another one of the remaining three relatively quickly (within 1 second), the app freezes.

The app will not freeze:

- When the same date picker is selected.
- When the user selects 'Done'.
- When the user waits 1 to 2 seconds before selecting a new time picker.

The time pickers work fine on any device older than, but not including, iOS 15.
On iOS 15 and above, the freezing only occurs when the OS is iOS (phone), but never on iPadOS.

I have tried setting `definesPresentationContext` to true, but to no avail.

I could not find any other developers with this kind of issue on the internet, which is why im resorting to StackOverflow.

The error that arises:
`[Presentation] Attempt to present <_UIDatePickerContainerViewController: 0x15303b6e0> on <ViewController: 0x150d068f0> (from <ViewController: 0x150d068f0>) which is already presenting <_UIDatePickerContainerViewController: 0x150e16650>.`

So my question is, is there anyone else that has experienced freezing because of time pickers on iOS15+ with phones only?